# How to Remove Special Characters in this Javascript Code

Tags: javascript

How do I remove special characters in the specific code below? I've been trying to use replace with var = t,  but it has not worked properly. When a person enters a comma in the number they want converted to words, it cuts the sentence.

Thanks!

```
var o=new Array("diez", "once", "doce", "trece", "catorce", "quince", "dieciséis", "diecisiete", "dieciocho", "diecinueve", "veinte", "veintiuno", "veintidós", "veintitrés", "veinticuatro", "veinticinco", "veintiséis", "veintisiete", "veintiocho", "veintinueve");
var u=new Array("cero", "uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "seis", "siete", "ocho", "nueve");
var d=new Array("", "", "", "treinta", "cuarenta", "cincuenta", "sesenta", "setenta", "ochenta", "noventa");
var c=new Array("", "ciento", "doscientos", "trescientos", "cuatrocientos", "quinientos", "seiscientos", "setecientos", "ochocientos", "novecientos");

function toWords(n)
{ 
  var n=parseFloat(n).toFixed(2);
  var p=n.toString().substring(n.toString().indexOf(".")+1);
  var m=n.toString().substring(0,n.toString().indexOf("."));
  var m=parseFloat(m).toString().split("").reverse();
  var t=" ";


  for (var i=0; i<m.length; i+=3)
  {
    var x=t;

    var b=m[i+1]!=undefined?parseFloat(m[i+1].toString()+m[i].toString()):parseFloat(m[i].toString());

    t=m[i+2]!=undefined?(c[m[i+2]]+" "):"";
    t+=b<10?u[b]:(b<30?o[b-10]:(d[m[i+1]]+(m[i]=='0'?"":(" y "+u[m[i]]))));
    t=t=="ciento cero"?"cien":t;
    if (2<i&&i<6)
      t=t=="uno"?"mil ":(t.replace("uno","un")+" mil ");
    if (5<i&&i<9)
      t=t=="uno"?"un millón ":(t.replace("uno","un")+" millones ");
    t+=x;
    //t=i<3?t:(i<6?((t=="uno"?"mil ":(t+" mil "))+x):((t=="uno"?"un millón ":(t+" millones "))+x));
  }

  return t;
}
```

Comment: you problem is not clear, what you want?

Comment: When you enter a comma in the value, the output is cut off. For example, if you put a comma in the value (5,644), it will say Five instead of Five Thousand Six Hundred Forty Four.

Answer (score 0):

u have `n= parseFloat(n)`... that will consider coma as floating point, use `n =parseFloat(n.replace(',',''));` but this is incorrect removal of comma

Comment: No, parseFloat will *not* consider comma as a floating point (it is hardwired to use the . as separator, independent of your current locale). It simply considers it a non-digit and stops parsing the input.

Comment: Thanks SilentTremor! Worked for me. Removing the comma won't be an issue in the BIRT report that I'm using

Comment: Well glad to hear that, yeah @Paul-Jan you are right.

Answer (score 0):

ParseFloat doesn't support thousand separators. If you want to support user input containing such separators, you'll have to manually strip them off.

```
function toWords(n)
{ 
  var n=parseFloat(n.replace(',','')).toFixed(2);
  ...
```